# Google Drive API watch channel is only 24h

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the v3 api drive file watch api. I just want to subscribe to the changes made in specific folders. I was able to establish the watch channel. However, the expiration date I receive is only 24h even when I set it manually to 7 days.

```
var expirationWatchTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7);
var channel = DriveService.Files.Watch(
                new Channel
                {
                    Address = _googleConfiguration.Value.WebHookUrl,
                    Type = "web_hook",
                    Id = projectDocumentFolderId.ToString(),
                    Expiration = expirationWatchTime.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
                },
                missingFolder.Id).Execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm checking the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) and it seems that subscribing to file resources changes will have a maximum expiration date of 24 hours. I'll quote the specific note:

> Note: For the Drive API, the maximum expiration time is 86400 seconds (1 day) after the current time for File resources and 604800 seconds (1 week) for Changes. If you don’t set the expiration property in your request, the expiration time defaults to 3600 seconds after the current time.

There is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218672/set-google-drive-push-notification-to-never-expire?rq=1) that it as well provides the same answer.